# How to send formfield values to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, flutter

I am trying to develop a Flutter mobile application and want to post the values (name, email and telephone) from a formfield to a NodeJS server. It's possible?

Comment: Yes it is......

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for sure. One of the solution:-

Your endpoint setup should look like:

```
const formidable = require('formidable');
app.post('/test/your/api', function(req, res) {  
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

        if (err) {
             return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
        }
       res.json({
           status: 'success'
        });
    }    
});
```

And you can use browser's native FormData class and axios as an http utility at frontend:

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/test/your/api';
const form = new FormData();
form.append('name', 'value');
form.append('gender','value');
axios.post(endpoint, form, { headers: form.getHeaders() }).then((res) => {
   console.log(res.data);
});
```